# Regex to match specific comments in code

Tags: c#, regex, comments

Are there any regex experts who can help me clean up the following source code?  I'm going through some existing code and I see several instances similar to the following:

```
public enum Numbers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// One = 1, 
    /// </summary>
    One = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// Two = 2, 
    /// </summary>
    Two = 2,

    /// <summary>
    /// Three = 3, 
    /// </summary>
    Three = 3,

    /// <summary>
    /// Four = 4 but don't use this because it will break everything, 
    /// </summary>
    Four = 4,
}
```

Unless someone can tell me that the comments for 1-3 are necessary, I'd like to do a find/replace (remove) on all of the comments that don't add any value to the code.  From browsing the code I think it's safe to assume that any line that resembles "/// word = number," can be replaced.  Cleaned up, I think it should look like:

```
public enum Numbers
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,

    /// <summary>
    /// Four = 4 but don't use this because it will break everything, 
    /// </summary>
    Four = 4,
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!  And by helping me, you are really helping yourself.  Because who knows, someday you might be maintaining this very code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With VS2008 FindAndReplace I tried this and worked;

**Find what:**

```
/// \<summary\>.*\n.*\=:b:d[:b,]*\n.*\<\/summary\>\n
```

**Replace with:**

```
(empty)
```

**Use:**

Regular expressions

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me thousands of unnecessary keystrokes and mouse highlights!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perl script which will remove such comments:

```
my $text = join "", <>;
$text =~ s{///\s+<summary>\s+///\s+\w+\s+=\s+\d+,\s+///\s+</summary>}{}g;
print $text;
```

Comment: `\s` already contains `\n`, so `[\s\n]+` can be written as `\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a unix-like os or have cygwin?

I've never done multiline matching with regex, but there's a link on using sed to do it...

http://www.ilfilosofo.com/blog/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/

I'll read and edit this answer later to apply it to your problem.  Or maybe someone else will.

Comment: Actually I'm using Visual Studio and I was going to try a Find/Replace using regex and replacing with an empty string.