# SQL Server: How to extract comments from stored procedures for deployment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

We have lots of stored procedures which all contain a lot of comments.
Is there a way to extract the comments from the stored procedures for deployment so the users can't see them when they modify a stored procedure with SQL Server Management Studio?

Note: We're using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Instead of hiding all of your "validates the employee type field, because the ID10Ts are liable to type *anything*" comments, you should probably just delete them. :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Full ACK. But our comments are mostly versioning info right in front of the actual CREATE PROCEDURE statement. But they still end up in the database. Also there are some comments with links to our PM software which users really don't have to see but are nevertheless useful for us.

Comment: This previous question will likely help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640321/regex-to-match-specific-comments-in-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the WITH ENCRYPTION option:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.foo 
WITH ENCRYPTION 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 'foo' 
--Try this just to make sure
END
```

before that make sure you keep the logic of the stored procedure in a safe place, since you won't have easy access to the procedure's code once you've saved it.

After that the user can't use **Enterprise Manager** or **sp_helptext** to get the Source Code but this can be cracked...

Comment: Yes that seems like a good idea anyway. Do you know whether there is a performance penalty doing so? I could find anything regarding this on MSDN, but I guess rather no.

Comment: Note that you can not debug the procedure anymore and profiling will only return aggregate information for the procedure once it is encrypted.

Comment: Encryption is not uncrackable, it is actually very easy to crack. It does impact performance. I see no solution to what he is asking except for using CLR.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption is great but if you need to allow users to make changes to stored procedures (as your initial question suggests) then encryption isn't your answer.  It'll hide the comments AND the code from the users.

If you want to leave the code visible but remove comments, you might want to use Management Studio to script out all your stored procedures, then use a macro/text editor like UltraEdit to find and remove all comments, and then run that script again to rebuild all the comment-less stored procedures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in my case going for encryption is the better solution as I don't need users to be able to modify the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that WITH ENCRYPTION is the way to go, since it can be cracked very easily. It was never meant to be impossible to decrypt. Even if it is not a complex encryption, it does impact execution on recompile, especially if the stored procedure requires constant recompiling (for instance if it uses a lot of temp tables and cursors).

There should be a way to create a stored procedure to remove all the text between -- and the next carriage return as well as between /* */ containers, then save the create / alter script as something else, maybe on your QA database, for instance. sp_execute_sql would be very much in use.

If not a stored procedure, any other application could be used to retrieve the stored procedures out of schema and then use regular expressions to do what I just described and spit out a new alter/create T-SQL code without the comments.